# Is it possible to "flip" canvas drawings? Any other workarounds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, flip

I've got a set of `<canvas>` elements that I am "flipping" around using [flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip). My problem is that the way flip works it's flipping the whole `<canvas>` element and that's creating a not-so-pretty effect while it's flipping... So what I am trying to accomplish is to "flip" in a similar way as flip! does, but within canvas. Or are there any other known workarounds?

Here's a little example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/4/.

I would like to flip the black triangles but when I use the flip method from the URL above it flips the whole canvas element which creates the not-so-nice effect.

I'm pretty sure you can just flip the whole image in canvas in a second but what I'm looking for is the whole animation too. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: If you click on the triangle it flips (albeit only half way) but if you pay attention to the animation you can see it's the whole `<canvas>` element that flips and not just the triangle.

Comment: Yes, it does now :-) I got to it before the "click" handler was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use CSS 3d Transforms and Transitions to perform a [card flipping animation on the canvas element](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html). flipping only a partial of the canvas element is only possible by programming the animation from scratch, since that would include manipulating the bitmap image pixel by pixel. Alternatively, you could transform the canvases matrix itself, but involves far more work then 3d Transition in relation to the Animation.

Comment: I see. Although those 3D transformations aren't widely supported... Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: in modern Browsers, 2D Tranforms are possible (IE9, FF3.5, Safari3, Chrome4, Android, iOS) and 3dTransforms are supported mainly by WebKit Browsers such as Safari5, Chrome, Android and iOS. They will be in IE10 and FF10..